# Out of memory when inserting records in SQLite, FireDac, Delphi

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I have a Delphi app that inserts some 200,000 records (about 1GB) into an SQLite database via the FireDac component TFDTable.  As it inserts, I can see the application memory increasing until I get an "Out of Memory Error".  I'm guessing it has something to due with cache and paging but I cant find anything that fixes it short of closing and reopening the database every 1000 records or so. Thoughts?

Edited...
Sorry for the thinly worded question...
The code was simple so I didn't include it but looks basically like this:

```
procedure DoIt;
begin
  myDB.Insert;
  myDBField1.AsString := StringOfChar('-',1000);
  myDB.Post;
end;
```

Now, I expect the memory might increase as the string is likely copied to the DB caches. If I look at the allocations using GetMemoryManagerState() I can actually see this. I would expect that at some point, the memory in the cache would be flushed as the data is written to disc.  However, it does not seem to be. It just keeps going until I get an "Out of Memory" error.

In general most of the object properties are all set to default states except selecting sqlite in the connection and adding fields to the table.

I know there is not a lot to go on here.  But I didn't think this would fail either and I was hoping someone may have had a similar issue.

Comment: How about you post some code that reproduces the issue? Also, your Delphi/FireDAC version could be important.

Comment: We can't debug a story.  See : [mcve].  At least show us *some* of the relevant code if not that.

Comment: Data-aware components bring quite some overhead with them that may get in the way for really large,but straight-forward jobs. That's why I created a 'clean' wrapper around the sqlite DLL: https://github.com/stijnsanders/TSQLite

Comment: There is an underlying data storage and it's natural that if you're not commiting your data into your DBMS, that storage is caching them and grows. Difficult to suggest here something without seeing your code, but consider at least using [Array DML technique](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Array_DML_(FireDAC)) for executing in batches.

Comment: Do you need that data on the client side? I have no experience with FireDAC, but you insert data into the dataset at client side, I find it natural that it takes up memory there. You have a string field with at least a length of 1000, and that times 200000 records. If you don't need that data on the client, you could maybe look into [executing commands in FireDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Executing_Commands_(FireDAC)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**TFDTable**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable) is a thin wrapper around a query object that can build SQL commands for operating with the underlying DBMS table. It has its own storage ([**Table**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.Table) object) into which it stores data fetched to the client as well as tuples that you insert. But all that is in memory, there's no underlying file cache.

Although that internal storage can be cleared whilst you're inserting, [**TFDTable**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDTable) is not a good object for inserting data in such amount. Better use query object like [**TFDQuery**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDQuery) which in combination with a batch command execution technique called [**Array DML**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Array_DML_(FireDAC)) can bring you real performance increase, even for local DBMS engine. And [**TFDQuery**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDQuery) won't be caching inserted tuples.

FireDAC supports this technique for SQLite natively when you use indexed parameter binding, e.g. this code should insert 200 times batch of 1000 unique tuples:

```
const
  BatchSize = 1000;
  TotalSize = 200000;
var
  Batch: Integer;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (:p1, :p2)';
  FDQuery.Params.BindMode := pbByNumber;
  FDQuery.Params.ArraySize := BatchSize;

  for Batch := 0 to TotalSize div BatchSize - 1 do
  begin
    for Index := 0 to BatchSize - 1 do
    begin
      FDQuery.Params[0].AsIntegers[Index] := (Batch * BatchSize) + Index;
      FDQuery.Params[1].AsWideStrings[Index] := 'Some Unicode string value';
    end;
    FDQuery.Execute(BatchSize, 0);
  end;
end;
```