# out of memory when insert record batch through jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

I want to copy a table (10 million records) in **originDB**(sqlite3) into another database called **targetDB**. 
The process of my method is:
read data from the origin table and generate a **ResultSet**, then generate corresponding insert sql about every record and execute **commit** to batch insert when the count of record reach 10000.
 The code as follow:

```
public void transfer() throws IOException, SQLException {
    targetDBOperate.setCommit(false);//batch insert
    int count = 0;
    String[] cols = parser(propertyPath);//get fields of data table
    String query = "select * from " + originTable;
    ResultSet rs = originDBOperate.executeQuery(query);//get origin table
    String base = "insert into " + targetTable;
    while(rs.next()) {
        count++;
        String insertSql = buildInsertSql(base,rs,cols);//corresponding insert sql
        targetDBOperate.executeSql(insertSql);
        if(count%10000==0) {
            targetDBOperate.commit();// batch insert
        }
    }
    targetDBOperate.closeConnection();
}
```

The follow picture is the trend of using memory, and vertical axis represents memory usage 
[image]

As we can say it will be bigger and bigger until *out of memory*. The stackoverflow has some relevant question such as [Out of memory when inserting records in SQLite, FireDac, Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975298/out-of-memory-when-inserting-records-in-sqlite-firedac-delphi)
, but I havent solve my problem for we use different implement method.
 My hypothesis is that when the count of record hasn't reach 10000, these corresponding insert sql will be cached in memory and they haven't been removed when execute commit by default? Every advice will be appreciate.

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) make sure you set autoCommit to `false`. 2) Use the real batch update [`addBatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095176/optimizing-batch-inserts-sqlite) and above all be sure you use in `insert` statement **bind variables** (It could be that this is the cause of your memory problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fetch 10M records in one go by doing the following. This will definitely eat your memory like anything

```
String query = "select * from " + originTable;
ResultSet rs = originDBOperate.executeQuery(query);//get origin table
```

Use paginated queries to read the batches and do batch updates according.

You are not even doing a batch-update You are simply firing 10K queries one after the other by doing the following code

```
String insertSql = buildInsertSql(base,rs,cols);//corresponding insert sql
    targetDBOperate.executeSql(insertSql);
    if(count%10000==0) {
        targetDBOperate.commit();// This simply means that you are commiting after 10K records
    }
```

Comment: Result sets don't necessarily materialize all rows at once. Doesn't sqlite honor the fetch size setting?

Comment: will the 10k insert sql released after execute commit method?

Answer (score 2):

By moving a higher number of rows in **SQLite** or any other relational database  you should follow some basic principles:

1) set `autoCommit` to **false**, i.e. do not commit each insert

2) use **batch update**, i.e. do not round trip for each row

3) use **prepared statement**, i.e. do not parse each insert.

Putting this together you get following code:

`cn` is the source connection, `cn2` is the target connection.

For each inserted row you call `addBatch`, but only once per `batchSize` you call `executeBatch` which initiates a round trip.

Do not forget a last `executeBatch` at the end of the loop and the final `commit`.

```
cn2.setAutoCommit(false)

String SEL_STMT = "select id, col1,col2 from tab1"
String INS_STMT = "insert into tab2(id, col1,col2) values(?,?,?)"

def batchSize = 10000


def stmt = cn.prepareStatement(SEL_STMT)
def stmtIns = cn2.prepareStatement(INS_STMT) 

rs = stmt.executeQuery()

while(rs.next())
  {
    stmtIns.setLong(1,rs.getLong(1))
    stmtIns.setString(2,rs.getString(2))
    stmtIns.setTimestamp(3,rs.getTimestamp(3))
    stmtIns.addBatch();
    i += 1

    if (i == batchSize) {
        def insRec = stmtIns.executeBatch();
        i = 0
        }

  }
rs.close()
stmt.close()

def insRec = stmtIns.executeBatch();

stmtIns.close()
cn2.commit()
```

Sample test with your size with sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1:

```
inserted rows: 10000000
total time taken to insert the batch = 46848 ms
```

I do not observe any memory issues or problems with a large transaction